# Как написать парсер кода на C/C++, C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, парсер, метрики

Необходимо написать парсер кода для подсчёта метрики Чепина.
Непонятен алгоритм написания парсера.

Comment: Или берите готовый парсер, или учите программирование, третьего варианта нету.

Comment: парсер _какого кода_?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень, очень, очень обширный. В качестве ответа можно было бы копипастнуть известную "книгу дракона", но она не войдёт в ответ. Поэтому предлагаю вам уточнить: в чём именно затруднения, на каком шаге вы остановились? У вас уже есть алгоритм, но вы не понимаете его логики? Вы не знаете, где найти алгоритм парсера? Вы хотите самостоятельно изобрести алгоритм парсера?

Answer (score 4):

> Необходимо написать парсер кода

Стандартно, для написания парсеров разного рода, в языке С используются утилиты lex(flex) и yacc (bison)

Посмотрите http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/lex-yacc-howto.html